# Can't Parse JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have this JSON response:

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0" ["id"]=> int(1) 
 ["result"]=> array(305) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["acct"]=> 
 string(16) "CtjSZlND9uw6-wCQ" ["customid"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> 
 string(8) "disabled" ["name"]=> string(34) "Adrenaline Offroad and 
 Performance" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["acct"]=> string(16) 
 "CtjSZVNxEYQkvQDy" ["customid"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(8) 
 "disabled" ["name"]=> string(10) "Akins Ford" } [2]=> 
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["acct"]=> string(16) "CtjSZlOMywBP1wDa" 
  ["customid"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(8) "disabled" 
  ["name"]=> string(20) "Akins Service Center" } [3]=> 
  object(stdClass)#5 (4) { ["acct"]=> string(16) "CtjSZ1G2OVQD6QDX" 
  ["customid"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(6) "active" ["name"]=> 
  string(17) "Ames Ford Lincoln" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { 
  ["acct"]=> string(16) "CtjSZVKCfAsRCQDn" ["customid"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["status"]=> string(8) "disabled" ["name"]=> string(17) "Anthony GMC 
  Buick" }
```

How do I parse things like ["id"], ["acct"], ["status"].

Answer (score 1):

From your `var_dump` I see that is already parsed.

So you can access it like:

`$myObject->jsonrpc` you will get a string `2.0`

`$myObject->id` you will get an int `1`

`$myObject->result` you will an array with objects

Comment: Here's what I have done:                                                                  $data = $response["result"];
foreach ($data as $val){
    print $val["acct"] . "--" . $val["name"] . "<br />";
} How do I access data with "->" symbol as I get error (e.g., $val->acct) gives an error.

Comment: can you provide the json string before parsed?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second parameter (`true`) to `json_decode` function.

Like: `$response = json_decode($json, true);`

> When second parameter is TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

For next time, check the php documentation using *[php.net/{function_name}](http://php.net/json_decode)*